# Agda allows for incorrect proofs?

Tags: agda

I was playing around a bit with proofs in Agda following PLFA, specifically the monus operator.

```
-- Monus
_∸_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
m ∸ zero = m
zero ∸ suc (m) = zero
suc (n) ∸ suc(m) = n ∸ m
```

And the problem I found is that I can make incorrect "proofs" that compile:

```
_ : 3 ∸ 5 ≡ 0
_ =
  begin
      3 ∸ 5
    ≡⟨⟩
      2 ∸ 4
    ≡⟨⟩
      1 ∸ 3
    ≡⟨⟩
      0 ∸ 3
    ≡⟨⟩
      0
    ∎
```

While it is true that 3 ∸ 5 ≡ 0, in the rules for the monus there is no rule that indicates that **1 ∸ 3 ≡⟨⟩ 0 ∸ 3**. The correct application of rule 3 would yield **1 ∸ 3 ≡⟨⟩ 0 ∸ 2**. How can I be sure that I only apply correct rules in each step of the proof, and reject this kind of proofs? Thank you.

Comment: Each step is accepted because all of these operations compute to 0. AFAIK there is no syntactic construct to assert that two terms are exactly one reduction step apart.

Comment: What you could do is try proving that `∀ n → n ∸ (2 + n) ≡ 0`, which should require more than reflexivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @Naïm Favier says in the comments is correct.

You're asking to mirror a particular computation, step-by-step, and Agda doesn't do that, it computes all the way. So it sees `0` all the way down.

If you want to reason about derivations, then you should create the monus *relation* that has two rules; from that relation, you can 'extract' the function, since it is a functional relation. But now that you have a proof-relevant relation, derivations are tangible, and you won't be able to write down an incorrect one.

Comment: Ok, I see. I was expecting of Agda to be a proof checker that rejected "incorrect proofs" of correct results.

Comment: Agda does reject incorrect proofs, it's just that the proof here is not considered incorrect by Agda since all of the terms are definitionally equal (and Agda does not distinguish between definitionally equal terms).